# Undefined WP_Query::has_posts()?

Tags: wp-query, loop, query

This must be wrong.

I was testing something so I did:

```
$queried_post = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1));
var_dump($queried_post->has_posts()); exit;
```

And I get the error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Query::has_posts()
```

I am working with this inside a class INSIDE the theme ....

`var_dump($queried_posts);` shows 5-6 posts. even if their were no posts I would get false. I should get .... true ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't `has_posts`, it is `have_posts`. You've just got the method name wrong. That's all.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods